# make a dir or find command follow shortcuts

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm currently trying to set up a batch file or something similar to run a search through a series of different file shares at my workplace.

I'm fairly new with CMD, but have managed to get what I'm looking for in one instance, and I'm now looking to apply that through several different files at once.

```
C:\Users\My Username> dir c:\Users\My Username\documents -path \appdata -prune -o *.xml /b /s >c:\users\My Username\documents\Filename
```

Above is the code I'm using currently to source from one file, omitting the Appdata file, as that was being returned & I didn't want its contents in the output.

However, this code above is simply a test that I've used; my end goal is to apply that to several different files accessible through the company, so for example,

```
DriveLetter:\SiteLocationFolder\SpecificFileShare\> dir DL:\SLF\SFS\ -path \UselessFolder -prune -o *xml /b /s >DL:\SLF\FileShareReportsFolder\
```

For the sake of anonymity, I've substituted in placeholder names in the file path.

My issue exists in that, in the Site Location Folder, all of the Specific File Shares are accessed through shortcuts, and I was wondering whether there was a string to allow CMD to run the dir through these shortcuts, or if I would instead have to run the batch file for each different Specific File Share?

Comment: You have used the term DOS even though I'm willing to bet you are not using it. There are also no such command options as -path, -prune or -o to the DIR command despite the fact you have reported that test line as working. I strongly advise that you reword/clarify what you want by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46039281/edit) your question.

Comment: This command looks like a hybrid of CMD's `dir` (e.g. `/b /s`) and Unix `find` (e.g. `-path \appdata -prune -o`). What shell is this?

Comment: This is using the command prompt from Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 2):

The `cmd.exe` shell `DIR` command will not follow shortcuts in the same way as a link. If you must use Windows shortcuts, you might need to look into https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=80659.0

Another way would be to make links using the Windows `mklink` command. Use `mklink /?` to read about it. Search the net to learn the differences between links and junctions.